# When sport or dport is used on INPUT of Iptables?

Tags: iptables

I want to block port 22 to users on my local network. My linux server controls the traffic with [`iptables`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html). Which rules are the most appropriate?

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -p tcp --sport 22 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

**Important: The rules are just an example. You guys can choose any example port in your answer**

I just want to know what are the scenarios in which `dport` and `sport` are used in the `INPUT` chain. The answer can be with other examples

PS: The question is aimed at blocking the access of the users of the local LAN network to this port (or any other), therefore the rule must only be for the interface of the local LAN network (not WAN). `$LAN` is a variable of LAN interface (e.g. `enp2s1`, `eth1`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j DROP
```

Will block INPUT dataframe from an SSH server. Then you won't be able to reach an external SSH server.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Will block INPUT dataframe from a SSH client. Then nobody could be able to reach your SSH server. I guess it is what you want.

Note: The usuall way to protect a host is to block everything, and allow what you need. Perhaps `ufw` should help you to make your protection. It is a more high level firewall which can be usefull for most needs. (`ufw` deals with the direction of a connection. `iptable`, with the direction of the dataframes a lower level).

Comment: Assuming SSH servers running in the default port. Dropping packets to/from port 22 would still allow access to an SSH server in some other port. It's also not too hard to create rules that look at the direction of the connection with `iptables`, just allow existing connections with `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`  and then make rules for new ones with e.g. `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 --source xyz -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know what are the scenarios in which `dport` and `sport` are used in the `INPUT` chain.

Typically, you are looking to restrict access to services either on your machine, or from your machine.  Since the initial packet in a TCP handshake is from the client to the server, it's more usual to either use `dport` in the `INPUT` chain to control access to a local service, or use `dport` in the `OUTPUT` chain to control access to a remove service (from the local host).

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP // prevents access to a local SSH server
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP // prevents access to a remote SSH server
```

Most TCP-based protocols don't care about the port that the client is bound to. You might, as an administrator, only allow access to a local service from a specific client port (remember that by default on Linux, port numbers under 1024 require extra privilege to bind to), but this isn't very common at all.

Comment: You did not include in your answer "INPUT -sport". I would appreciate if you fix it

Comment: Your question was asking about scenarios in which you would use `sport` in a rule for the `INPUT` chain. I answered with an example of a case where you're only allowing incoming connections from some privileged port. Are you looking for an example of some arbitrary iptables command that passes `-A INPUT --sport`, or are you asking about why you would do that?

Comment: It is that you gave an example of the OUTPUT chain and that is not in the question. I only need INPUT (sport and dport)

Comment: DHCP doesn't use TCP :)

Comment: @ilkkachu ???. I don't know what DHCP has to do with the question

Comment: @acgbox, that's up to you to decide, it's your question. It had to do with the answer, though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/740958/1

Comment: @acgbox ilkkachu was pointing out a mistake I made in the original answer.

Comment: @acgbox I don't really understand what you're asking. If you're looking for a rule that has `-p tcp --sport` in the `INPUT` chain, Frédéric did include one in their answer that has an effect of dropping access to external SSH servers, but my answer points out that this can be achieved by a rule of the form `-p tcp --dport` in the `OUTPUT` chain, which blocks the very first packet in the TCP handshake rather than the second. What is it exactly that you "need" a rule using `--sport` for?

Comment: It's not that I need the rule or not. I just want to understand when using sport and dport on INPUT